# Android Studio ARM64 AVD not supported by QEMU2 on Linux x86_64?

Tags: android-studio, arm, android-virtual-device, qemu

I've created a virtual device of ARM64 in Android Studio on Linux x86_64.
When I start it from GUI, it shows that the process is terminated.
When I start it from command line with:
`./emulator -avd VM2`
it shows:
`PANIC: Avd's Cpu Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.`
details:
host CPU: Intel Core i5-4210U; Intel VT enabled; 64-bit;
host OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11; 64-bit;
Android Studio: Bumblebee for Linux; 4.0 for Linux;
Android System: API32 arm64-v8a; 12.0 arm64-v8a;
the system supports KVM;

I've tried:
completely reinstall Android Studio;
different versions of Android Studio;
different versions of Android ARM64;
install qemu-system-arm; gcc-arm...;

But none of them works. How can I solve it?

Comment: Tried with Android Studio 4.2.2 and I am getting the same thing also

Answer (score 0):

I recreated virtual-device and it's working! Also, you can check your android-studio log file for more information. Log file's path is: "YourDiskName:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\YourAndroidStudioVersion\log\idea.log". It can be usefull for you.